# Maximum android app package name character length for google play console?

Tags: android, react-native, mobile, google-play-console

Have some one experience any character length limit of a package name for an app while uploading to google play console ? if yes then please tell the maximum number length of characters for package name.

I have to create a long package name like com.abccompany.livescore.livecricketscore.livefootbalscore

Basically I want targeted keyword in my playstore app url like this below for **ASO optimization** point of view

**play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.abccompany.livescore.livecricketscore.livefootbalscore**

If some one experience any issue regarding long package name while uploading on play console then let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Google Play says

> Your APK or Android App Bundle's package name must be in the following format "com.example.myapp". It may contain letters (a-z), numbers, and underscores (_). It must start with a lowercase character. It must be 150 characters or fewer.

According to this message, the applicationId can have to 150 characters